# Udon soup seasoning

Tags: spices, soup, japanese-cuisine

What is the name of the seasoning traditionally available for the diner to add to their Udon soup and what is in it?

I'm referring to the (I think) mix of spices that add a bit of a kick to the soup.  I've seen this provided as an accompaniment to Udon in Los Angeles and Japan, but I can't remember what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a Seven Spice Powder (Shichimi Togarashi) that may vary somewhat depending on where you are; [It's something like this](http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/Articles/Exotic-Herbs-Spices-and-Salts-639/togarashi.aspx). Probably available at most asian grocery stores or on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002YGSJQ).